# Iphone simulator without iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its quite bundled into the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the SDK.  You can get it free at (developer.apple.com/ios). If you want to just use the simulator you must install XCode but you can delete it after you install it.